# How changing planetary ring affects the migration of terrestrial fauna?

Tags: moons, electromagnetism, gas-giants, planetary-rings

Imagine a gas giant as massive as Jupiter has a enormous planetary ring which will expand and contract throughout its orbit around a main sequence star.

Then there is a moon as massive as Mars and it has a molten core and liquid water on its surface, usually certain migratory animals on Earth develop the ability to sense and trace the magnetic field to their respective breeding ground. However on the hospitable moon this pattern is disrupted by the changes of the ring, how is it possible?

Comment: don't try to sneak a second question in the main one, it would make your question too broad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jupiter is known for having a strong magnetic field. Let's say that this planet has the same.

Being so strong, it simply makes sense that no living species would adapt to use a non stable reference, such as the magnetic field resulting from the interaction of the moon with the planet, for migration patterns.

Incidentally the magnetic field also disturbs the orbits of the particles constituting the rings. What you describe is simple correlation, not causality.